# Query/subquery issue in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I got stuck in creating a subquery in my query (MySQL).

Table name: `log2016`

Data record started in October and the table looks like:

```
| Date                | Temp | Hum | Cond          |
| 2016-10-01 14:03:40 | 13.6 | 60  | cloudy        |
| 2016-10-15 00:07:37 | 10.1 | 81  | partly cloudy |
   ...
| 2016-11-02 13:47:22 | 12.8 | 74  | partly cloudy |
  ...
```

First of all, I want to select all data from `2016-10-01 00:00:00` until `2016-11-01 00:00:00`.

WHERE clause:

```
WHERE `Date` < '2016-11-01 00:00:00'
```

Second I want to select the row "Cond" as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT `Cond`, COUNT(`Cond`) AS `Anz` FROM `log2016` GROUP BY `Cond`";
```

This query works fine, but if I put the WHERE clause in this query like e.g.

```
$query = "SELECT `Cond`, COUNT(`Cond`) AS `Anz` FROM `log2016` WHERE `Date` < '2016-11-01 00:00:00' GROUP BY `Cond`";
```

it won't work.

I googled a lot and also tried different things to solve my problem, but nothing worked.

**EDIT:**

Here is the whole code:

```
<?php

include_once("../../mysql/Wetterdatenlogger.php"); 
include_once("Wetter_2016.php");

    if (isset ($_GET['Periode']) && $_GET['Periode'] == 'ALL ') 
        {        
            $query = "SELECT `Wetter`, COUNT(`Wetter`) AS `Anzahl` FROM `log2016` GROUP BY `Wetter`";                
            $result = mysqli_query($db_link_Wetter, $query);

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {
                    $Wetter1 = $row['Wetter'];
                    $Wetter = "'".$Wetter1."'";
                    $Anz = $row['Anzahl'];

                    $data[] = "[$Wetter, $Anz]";
                }
        }

    if (isset ($_GET['Periode']) && $_GET['Periode'] == 'OKT.') 
        {      
            $query = "SELECT `Wetter`, COUNT(*) AS `Anzahl` FROM 
                          (
                            SELECT * FROM `log2016` WHERE `Datum/Zeit` < '2016-11-01 00:00:00'
                          ) 
                        GROUP BY `Wetter`" ;

            $result = mysqli_query($db_link_RPI_1, $query);

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {
                    $Wetter1 = $row['Wetter'];
                    $Wetter = "'".$Wetter1."'";
                    $Anz = $row['Anzahl'];

                    $data[] = "[$Wetter, $Anz]";
                }
        }
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#container8').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'pie',
                options3d: {
                    enabled: true,
                    alpha: 45,
                    beta: 0
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Wetter 2016'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.2f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    depth: 35,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '{point.name}'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Wetter 2016',
                data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>]
            }]
        });
    });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<form method="GET" id="choice" class="Wetter" action="Wetter_get_data_2016.php">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="Periode" value="OKT." class="input_Wetter">
            <input type="submit" name="Periode" value="NOV." class="input_Wetter">
            <input type="submit" name="Periode" value="DEZ." class="input_Wetter">
            <input type="submit" name="Periode" value="ALL " class="input_Wetter">
        </form>

        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

        <div id="container8" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Output for "ALL":

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhbTE.png)

Output for "OKT" - nothing is displayed

Comment: Please show your desired output.

Comment: what mean doesnt work? Error? Wrong result?

Comment: What do you mean by id don't work? Are you getting wrong data? If so, show us a sample data with the current output and the desired output. Are you getting any excepction? If so, show us the exception. Are you...?

Comment: this work fine form me, see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de154/1

Comment: strange, it works on fiddle but not for my code?

Comment: *doesn't work* - the best explanation ever for any type of problem. Luckily, we humans have evolved and now can use telepathy to find out what the unlucky OP meant when he said it "doesn't work". -1 for for using "doesn't work" as explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to make an inner select with the date filtering, and the outer select with the grouping, something like:

```
SELECT Cond, COUNT(*) AS Anz FROM 
  (
    SELECT * FROM log2016 WHERE Date < '2016-11-01 00:00:00'
  ) 
GROUP BY Cond ;
```

Comment: why you need that?

Comment: You mean splitting it into inner/outer selects, right? There is no particular reason except to verify that the basic concept of the query is correct. If this provides the correct and desired result, the query can be re-phrased to a single statement. See? Having the query that way, you can easily test the inner one and then the complete query (I sometimes use this method for debugging my own code).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunatelly this didn't work.

Comment: Saying _It does not work_ doesn't help us to help you. What is the error (if any)? What is the output (if any)? What is it that it makes it  **not working**?

Comment: I edited my first post, so you can see the whole code, but I can't find the error. Ido not understand, why the query works fine without the WHERE clause but not within it.

Comment: Last attempt... Why do you say **it does not work**?

Comment: because no chart is displayed

Comment: COME ON MAN!!!! How do you know that no data is displayed **BECAUSE NO DATA WAS RETRIEVED** or **BECAUSE SOME OTHER REASON AT YOUR CLIENT SIDE**? **_I GIVE UP!!!!_**

Comment: An upvote to ease your frustration, @FDavidov - sympathies! When you get a moment it may be worth deleting and reposting that all-caps comment with something a bit more gentle - even if readers can understand why it was posted `:-)`.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Problem is solved - there was a "copy & paste" error in my code.

Query works now.

Thanks to all helpers!